# What is the cost of using a Chainlink Oracle?

Tags: oracles, chainlink

I use the [market.link](https://market.link/) to check available jobs and each job has its own price in terms of link. My question is how many times this fee will be paid?

**For example:**

Let's say the API GET request costs `0.01 link`. If I trigger a function that triggers ORACLE for a GET call, are we going to pay only 0.01 no matter how many miners execute it? Or is it going to cost `0.01 x numberOfMiners` since each transaction will run by all the miners of the network?

Comment: Miners get their payment in Ether. This `0.01 link` fee sounds like something related specifically to Chainlink's system, which has nothing to do with mining of course. And as I explained to you in an answer on [your previous question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/90687/16043), the number of miners on the network has nothing to do with how much gas fee you pay for a given transaction. As far as you're concerned, you may assume that there's a single miner that you are paying to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A few clarifications

1. Chainlink is not mined, but paid to operators to request data
2. Node operators set their own prices, so when you see a node operator is charging `0.1 LINK` that is per API call / data request.
3. When you make a request, you choose the specific oracle you want to use. [1 request goes to 1 oracle](https://docs.chain.link/docs/architecture-request-model). If you want a [decentralized answer (which you should) you make requests to several oracles](https://docs.chain.link/docs/architecture-decentralized-model). Each oracle you make a request to is paid the amount they charge. So if you want 7 oracles to respond, you send 7 individual requests each with their own payment.
4. [Price Feeds](https://docs.chain.link/docs/get-the-latest-price) are examples of data that has already gone through the process above, and posted the data to make it public. So you don't have to make any requests since the data is already on-chain.

Similar to how [blockchains have their own transaction gas](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3/what-is-meant-by-the-term-gas), oracles have this oracle gas.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am still unclear regarding the number of times the link needs to be paid. A transaction that requests, says ETH price, will send this request to oracles. This cost 0.1 link for example. To reach consensus on the ethereum network, this call will run by the other nodes. Do they need to pay as well?

Comment: @EmrahSarıboz I have updated the response

Comment: I realized that my question is not detailed enough to remove the uncertainty I have. Thus, I asked a new questions regarding this. I would appreaciate if you can look at it.

Comment: Excellent and very clarified explanation for someone who is giving is first steps in chainlink.  Do this process applies to VRF as well? In the scenario of generating a random number we would be using VRF and for this on the 3rd point we wouldn't need the decentrilized approach. It would be enough 1 request. Am I right?

Comment: VRF is a little different since it comes with a random number proof, which makes it ok, the worst that can happen is the node won't respond. It can't give a "bad" random number. However, newer versions are being worked on with something called "threshold signatures" which allows many nodes to respond with random number proofs - meaning 100% decentralized and uptime.